# Lauching JRuby from Aptana Studio 3 on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, jruby, aptana

I'm running Aptana 3.0.6 on Windows XP
I also have JRuby 1.6.4 installed and the bin directory on my PATH

I'm very confused about how to launch JRuby from the console or by running a script. 
Aptana looks for ruby on the PATH, but JRuby is launched with `JRuby`. 
As far as I can tell it is not possible to launch JRuby as `Ruby` on Windows.

Has anyone found a way of using JRuby in Aptana on Windows?

On a Unix/OSX box I could use rvm to handle this. Pik on windows doesn't help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Found a clue in another post on this site. From Linux or Mac, you would just create a sym-link called ruby to your jruby executable and be done with it. Without that benefit in Windows (thanks Bill!), you can create a wrapper script in your jruby bin directory (ruby.bat) that will effectively do the same thing (assuming you already have jruby/bin in your path). It was posted elsewhere as just referencing "jruby". I found I had to include the full path for Aptana to resolve the reference.

ruby.bat:

```
@C:\devel\jruby-1.6.5\bin\jruby %*
```